# Trying to figure out how to send email straight from my iOS app? Mandrill or Mailgun Options

Tags: ios, objective-c, sendmail, mandrill, mailgun

Im trying to figure out how to implement a way to send an email straight from within my app to my email when the user submits. Essentially the user is filling out a brief form with his/her info/descriptions and I would like to take all the completed field values in that form and send that to my email after user hits send. I'm aware of the option to direct the user to their mail composer, but really would not like to use that, as it takes away from the point of the form.

I've tried looking at Mandrill and Mailgun, but having difficulty understanding how to implement the api, or basically set it up, I'm also a obj c beginner. Any help to set this up from scratch on my existing project would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

it s a VERY bad practice. if you want to save data, create an api for that and make the app send data to that api.